# jQuery UI Dialog confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery UI Dialog to display a confirmation prior to executing the action...in this case navigating to the selected link....but in another case, I might like to use AJAX delete.

I thought I could pass the action as parameter of the custom_confirm function:

```
   $("a.edit").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       custom_confirm('Please Note:',
           function(){
               location.href = $(this).attr('href');
           }
       );
   });

   function custom_confirm(prompt, action, title){
    if (title === undefined) title = "Are you sure?";
    if ($("#confirm").length == 0){
        $("#main div.inner").append('<div id="confirm" title="' + title + '">' + prompt + '</div>');
        $("#confirm").dialog({buttons: {'Proceed': function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); action; }, Cancel: function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); }}});
    }
    else {
        $("#confirm").html(prompt);
        $("#confirm").dialog('open');
    }
}
```

It's not working.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

---

Thanks for the quick responses guys. I tried your suggestion, but it's still not executing function that is passed as parameter.

```
    $("a.edit").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       custom_confirm('Please Note:',
           function(){
console.log(href);
               location.href = href;
           }
       );
   });
```

---

Cleaned up the custom_confirm function, added the close option:

```
function custom_confirm(prompt, action, title){
    if (title === undefined) title = "Are you sure?";
    $("#main div.inner").append('<div id="confirm" title="' + title + '">' + prompt + '</div>');
    $("#confirm").dialog({position: 'top', width: 700, modal: true, resizable: false, show: "fold", hide: "blind", buttons: {'Proceed': function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); action(); }, Cancel: function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); }}, close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).remove();}});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  If you are passing a function as a parameter to another function, you need to call the parameter as a funciton

```
action()
```

Instead of as a variable

```
action
```

Hope that helps

```
$("a.edit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    custom_confirm('Please Note:',
        function(){
            location.href = href;
        }
    );
});

function custom_confirm(prompt, action, title){
    if (title === undefined) title = "Are you sure?";
        if ($("#confirm").length == 0){
            $("#main div.inner").append('<div id="confirm" title="' + title + '">' + prompt + '</div>');
            $("#confirm").dialog({buttons: {'Proceed': function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); action(); }, Cancel: function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); }}});
        }
        else {
            $("#confirm").html(prompt);
            $("#confirm").dialog('open');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the `this` variable with a closure.

[See this example.](http://jsbin.com/ikeha) (improved)

```
   $("a.edit").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       custom_confirm('Please Note:',
           (function (element) {
             return function(element){
               location.href = $(element).attr('href');
           })(this)
       );
   });
```

But what you're trying to do could be done with the following probably just as easy:

```
$("a.edit").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure about that?"))
       e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I was hoping to use the jQuery UI Dialog plugin....but if it's getting too complicated I could use the native javascript confirm function.

Comment: Now it's the regular jQueryUI dialog. You'll need to get the dialog to come back after they've asked not to proceed the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or simply:

```
$("a.edit").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       custom_confirm('Please Note:',
           function(){
               location.href = href;
           }
       );
   });
```

Comment: Yeah, we're both right, but there are some other issues in the code that I haven't quite ironed out.